# How to set Alert checkbox values and label to loop and display from server

Tags: typescript, ionic2

This is the sample alert from Ionic 2 about alert checkbox

```
     doCheckbox() {
       let alert = this.alertCtrl.create();
       alert.setTitle('Which planets have you visited?');

      alert.addInput({
        type: 'checkbox',
        label: 'Alderaan',
        value: 'value1',
        checked: true
       });

      alert.addInput({
        type: 'checkbox',
        label: 'Bespin',
        value: 'value2'
       });

     alert.addInput({
        type: 'checkbox',
        label: 'Coruscant',
        value: 'value3'
      });


     alert.addButton('Cancel');
     alert.addButton({
       text: 'Okay',
       handler: data => {
          console.log('Checkbox data:', data);
          this.testCheckboxOpen = false;
          this.testCheckboxResult = data;
         }
       });
    alert.present().then(() => {
    this.testCheckboxOpen = true;
   });
  }
 }
```

my values are from server.... for example, courses

```
      this.schoolAppUsers.loadCourses().subscribe(courses =>{
          this.courses = courses;
        }
```

.... how do I loop through courses and assign them to value accordingly
and can someone explain that last part of the example:

```
     this.testCheckboxOpen = false;
     this.testCheckboxResult = data;

    alert.present().then(() => {
        this.testCheckboxOpen = true;
      });
```

... can someone help , thanx

user.ts:

```
  export interface User {
UserID: number;
name: string;
username: string;
password: string;
userIDNumber: string;
role: number;
Course: string;
CourseName: string;
CourseID: number;
Venue: string;
message: string;
  }
```

service.ts

```
 loadCourses(): Observable<User>{
return this.http.get(`${this.userApiUrl}/getCourses.php`)
  .map(res => <User>res.json());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To loop through you can call for example

```
schoolAppUser.loadCourses().subscribe(response =>{

    // loop through the list, assigning each item as 'course'
    for (let course of courses) {
       alert.addInput({
            type: 'checkbox',
            label: course.name,
            value: course.id
       });
    }
});
```

Comment: this.schoolAppUsers.loadCourses().subscribe(courses => {
      
      for (let course of courses){

      }

courses gives an error : Type 'User' is not an array type or string type ???

Comment: try a `console.log(JSON.stringify(courses));` to see what object you're **really** getting, because this means you do not get a list of `courses`

Comment: this is what i get 
 [{"CourseID":1,"CourseName":"Mathematics"},           {"CourseID":3,"CourseName":"Chemistry"},{"CourseID":5,"CourseName":"English Language"},{"CourseID":15,"CourseName":"Biology"},{"CourseID":16,"CourseName":"Literature"},{"CourseID":17,"CourseName":"Physics"}]

Comment: sorry , it should be (let course of course[0]) 

right ?

Comment: No, the `let course of courses` is basically a 'for each element currently named `course` in the list named `courses` do ....'. But your `courses` looks like a proper list

Comment: This is what im doing ` this.schoolAppUsers.loadCourses().subscribe(courses => {
      for (let course of courses[0]){
        // console.log(course);
        alert.addInput({
          type: 'checkbox',
          label: course.CourseName,
          value: course.CourseID
        });
      }
    })`
this code is just after `alert.setTitle` and before `alert.addButton`
but parameters do not pass , i get an alert with title only and buttons

Comment: Is the output you provided above from `let course of courses` or `let course of courses[0]`? Talking about `[{"CourseID":1,"CourseName":"Mathematics"}, {"CourseID":3,"CourseName":"Chemistry"},{"CourseID":5,"Cours‌​eName":"English Language"},{"CourseID":15,"CourseName":"Biology"},{"CourseID‌​":16,"CourseName":"L‌​iterature"},{"Course‌​ID":17,"CourseName":‌​"Physics"}] `

Comment: None actually , it was from 
`schoolAppUser.loadCourses().subscribe(courses=>{console.log(courses)}`

Comment: Aaaah okay I understand. and your `loadCourses()` is basically a `http` call that returns the response right? I'll edit my answer. (btw don't use `courses[0]` it returns only the first element in the list, not all)

Comment: yes, with observable, course[0] is ok , cuz the objects are inside an array , otherwise it shows wrong and code is underlined red line

Comment: `json()` does not exist on type 'User' this User is user model => in my service , `Observable<User>`

Comment: Ok, what properties does `User` have? Because you're returning this model instead of the list of courses (or at least define it like that in your service) It shows a red line because you told him you were returning a `User` but instead you expect a list to come out, so naturally you can't iterate over an Object

Comment: for example, i have these `CourseName: string;` `CourseID: string;`

Comment: Ok, but you say you're returning a **single** User with `Observable<User>` wouldn't you want to return **all**? So wouldn't it then be `Observable<Array<User>>`? I don't really understand why you called the model `User` when it is a `Course` though :p

Comment: then how come when I subscribe I receive all courses!!

Comment: I don't know, I didn't write your code, can't see it either.

Comment: Add your schoolAppUser.loadCourses() and your User model **edit the answer**